# How to add innerHTML to an existing attribute

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to add a `<button>` to a canvas, and I thought adding it like this may work, but it doesn't!! How do you add a `<button>` element to innerHTML inside a canvas?

Earlier (in case this helps,):

`ctx = myGameArea.context;`

```
<script>
stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        ctx.fillStyle="red";
        ctx.font="80px Georgia";
        ctx.fillText("You died",125,120);
        //this next part doesn't work!!!
        ctx.innerHTML = ("<button onclick='startGame()'>Restart</button>");
    }
}
</script>
```

For full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece; 
var myObstacle;
var transitionBlock;
var blockTransition;

function startGame() {
myGamePiece = new component(40, 40, "#00ff00ff", 50, 140);
myObstacle  = new component(80, 37, "#cf0000ff", 240, 0);
transitionBlock=new component(10, 80, "#f1f1f1ff", 590, 120);
blockTransition=new component(10, 80, "#f1f1f1ff", -40, 120);
myGameArea.start(); 
}

var myGameArea = {
canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 560;
    this.canvas.height = 320;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        myGameArea.key = false;
    })
},
clear : function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
},
stop : function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.font="80px Georgia";
    ctx.fillText("You died",125,120);
}
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.speedX = 0;
this.speedY = 0;    
this.x = x;
this.y = y;    
this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
        crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
}
}

function updateGameArea() {
if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    myGameArea.stop();
} else {
    myGamePiece.update();
    myGameArea.clear();
    myObstacle.update()
    transitionBlock.update();
    blockTransition.update();
    myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
    myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
}
    if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 65) {myGamePiece.speedX = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 68) {myGamePiece.speedX = 3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 87) {myGamePiece.speedY = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 83) {myGamePiece.speedY = 3; } else {myGamePiece.speedX = 0; myGamePiece.speedY = 0;}
    myGamePiece.update();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't add a dom element to the context render engine. Add it to the dom relative to the canvas element and you absolute position to put the button in the place you desire.

Comment: Whaat?!??!?!? May you please elaborate on that??

Comment: HTML inside a canvas is not possible , however what you can do is to give your button an absolute position on the top of your canvas

Comment: Can you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML inside a canvas is not possible , however what you can do is to give your button an absolute position on the top of your canvas.
Here is a small example:

```css
button{
position:absolute;
left:100px;
top:50px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece; 
var myObstacle;
var transitionBlock;
var blockTransition;

function startGame() {
myGamePiece = new component(40, 40, "#00ff00ff", 50, 140);
myObstacle  = new component(80, 37, "#cf0000ff", 240, 0);
transitionBlock=new component(10, 80, "#f1f1f1ff", 590, 120);
blockTransition=new component(10, 80, "#f1f1f1ff", -40, 120);
myGameArea.start(); 
}

var myGameArea = {
canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 560;
    this.canvas.height = 320;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        myGameArea.key = false;
    })
},
clear : function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
},
stop : function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.font="80px Georgia";
    ctx.fillText("You died",125,120);
}
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.speedX = 0;
this.speedY = 0;    
this.x = x;
this.y = y;    
this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
        crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
}
}

function updateGameArea() {
if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    myGameArea.stop();
} else {
    myGamePiece.update();
    myGameArea.clear();
    myObstacle.update()
    transitionBlock.update();
    blockTransition.update();
    myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
    myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
}
    if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 65) {myGamePiece.speedX = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 68) {myGamePiece.speedX = 3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 87) {myGamePiece.speedY = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 83) {myGamePiece.speedY = 3; } else {myGamePiece.speedX = 0; myGamePiece.speedY = 0;}
    myGamePiece.update();
}
</script>
<button>Hello I am a button floating on the top of the canvas</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the example the button is floating over the canvas, but not inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <canvas style="width:300px; height: 300px;" />
    <button style="position:absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%>hello</button>
</div>
```